# Copy Virtualmin's scheduled backup settings

Tags: backups, webmin

Just wondering if there is a quick way to copy all of my scheduled backup settings from one virtualmin server to another?

I have migrated all of the websites across with no problems, but though I would check if anyone knows how to import the backup settings or has a quicker way of setting them up?

I have quite a lot of separate backups configured, e.g. for each day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc) and each month (Jan, Feb, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but found the answer to my question.

It turns out that these settings can be bundled into your backup, you just need to go to:

**Virtualmin -> Backup & Restore -> Backup Virtual Servers**

From there you drop down the **Features and Settings** and make sure **Scheduled Virtualmin backups** is selected (under Virtualmin settings to also backup)

Hope this helps someone else tearing their hair out!